# C# How to overload the add method with two different strings

Tags: c#

I have been trying to build the following Text Adventure and have reached an error that I cannot figure out how to resolve. The error is:

> Assets/My_Scripts/MH_Script.cs(19,23): error CS1501: No overload for method Add' takes 2' arguments

Here is the beginning code for `MH_Script.cs`, the list is rather long since this is a Text Adventure.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MH_Script {

    public static List<MH_ScriptManager> sList = new List<MH_ScriptManager>();

        public MH_Script(){

        sList.Add("start", "You awaken in a sweltering room....
```

There are more strings added to `sList` in the same manner followed by:

```
public string SendScript(string state){
        string returnthis = "";
        foreach(MH_ScriptManager sm in sList){
            if(sm.getState() == state){
                returnthis = sm.getStory();
            }
        }
        return returnthis;
    } 
}
```

and here is `MH_ScriptManager`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MH_ScriptManager{


    public Helpers.STATE gState;
    public string gScript;
    public string getCurrentState(){
        return gState;
    }

    public MH_ScriptManager (string state, string script){
        gState = Helpers.ParseEnum<Helpers.STATE>(state);
        gScript = script;
    }

    public string getStory(){
        return gScript;
    }

    public string getState(){
        return gState.ToString();
    }

    public void setStory(string script){
        gScript = script;
    }

    public void setState(string state){
        gState = Helpers.ParseEnum<Helpers.STATE>(state);
    }

    public bool compareStatetoString(string compare){
        if (gState == Helpers.ParseEnum<Helpers.STATE> (compare))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Can somebody please explain to me what I am doing wrong, and how I can go about resolving this error in the future?

Comment: Am I not able to do this? My instructor told me I should go about it in this way the course ended before she answered me back about the error. I'm literally just trying to learn this language and it is my first.

Answer (score 3):

[`List.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) takes single argument, but in this case you are passing two arguments, which is causing an exception.

Also `sList` is of type  `MH_ScriptManager` , so what you need is

```
sList.Add(new MH_ScriptManager("start", "You awaken in a sweltering room..."));
```

Comment: This threw back a different error `MH_Script.cs(13,222): error CS1729: The type 'MH_ScriptManager' does not contain a constructor that takes '2' arguments`

Comment: It has the constructor that takes two arguments `MH_ScriptManager (string state, string script)`, reason could be something else.

Comment: I also add it as `sList.Add(new MH_ScriptManager("start", "You awaken...`));` because I believe the > after Script Manager was a typo.

Comment: Ahh.. yes :-). Sorry about that, if this resolves your issue mark this as answer by clicking green check mark.

Comment: It has not, I just get a different error as I stated above.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Add` method should have one argument but you give it two arguments, so

```
 sList.Add("start", "You awaken in a sweltering room);
```

change to:

```
 sList.Add("You awaken in a sweltering room)
```

Comment: I realize this, it was not what I was trying to accomplish though. Thank you for your feedback!